# How to fix "InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table X in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space"

Tags: mysql

Mysql doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"database"."table"' in the cache.
Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 1290.
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you read the following articles: [How to recover an orphaned .ibd file with MySQL 5.6](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/11/05/how-to-recover-an-orphaned-ibd-file-with-mysql-5-6/) and [Recover Corrupt MySQL Database](https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/). They can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue today while copying a datadir from one server to another, the answer I m gonna post might not be a direct one.
I have mistakenly added the innodb_force_recovery option in my configuration file thats the reason for the error, innodb_force_recovery value was set to 5.
Post removing the innod_force_recover option I got rid of this issue.